How do I prove this 8th grade geometry question about triangles?
Let $\triangle ABC$ $\angle BAC < 90^\circ$ and $\angle ABC < 90^\circ$ but $\angle BAC > \angle ABC$; $CH$ is height $(H \in AB)$ and $M$ is the midpoint of the line segment $AB$;
$\angle ACH = \angle BCM$. Prove that $\angle ACB = 90^\circ$

I tried constructing a circumcircle outside $\triangle CMH$ and marking the intersection points with $AC$ and $BC$. As you can see $DE \parallel HM$. Then I started angle chasing but got nowhere. I thought of proving that $\triangle CDH$ is isosceles. If I were to do that, I would be able to prove that DE is the perpendicular bisector of $CH$. And from there I would show that $\triangle CDE \cong \triangle DHE \cong \triangle DEM$. Since $\angle CHM = \angle CDM = \angle CEM$ therefore $CDME$ will be a rectangle.

Welcome to MSE. Take a tour. Add your attempts to avoid gaining downvote. Tell us what you have tried.

Also try adding an image. Or create one here.

Let $O$ be the circumcentre of $ABC$, and let $E$ lie on the circumcircle of $ABC$ so that $CE$ bisects $\angle BCA$. Then observe that $AE = BE$ since the angles subtended by these chords are equal (by definition). Hence, $O$, $M$, $E$ must be collinear (since they're all equidistant from $A$ and $B$), and $OE \perp AB$. This also implies $OE \parallel CH$.
Now $\angle ECH = \angle CEO$ by these parallel lines, and $\angle CEO = \angle ECO$ since $OCE$ is an isosceles triangle. We conclude that $\angle ECH = \angle ECO$. Since $EC$ bisects $\angle ACB$, it follows that $\angle ACH = \angle BCO$.
From the question, $\angle ACH = \angle BCM$. If $M \neq O$, it follows that $C, O, M$ are collinear, so $CM \perp AB$. But this would imply $\angle ABC = \angle BAC$, contradicting the question. Hence, $M = O$, so $O$ lies on $AB$. Hence, $AB$ is a diameter of the circumcircle, and thus $\angle ACB = 90^\circ$.

In any triangle the orthocenter and circumcenter both cut off equal angles $\alpha'=90-\alpha$ as in the diagram below (acute case shown). You are given that $\angle{ACH}=\angle{MCB}$, implying, because $O$ lies on $OM \perp AB$, that $O=M$. Thus $AB$ is a diameter of the circumcircle, implying the angle at $C$ is right.

